# Validate inputs separtely

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net login page, where there is input under asp:Login and on same page inputs out side asp:Login. When I click submit button inside asp:Login the jquery validator can validate the inputs inside asp:Login even if focus is in other input outside asp:Login. But when I click submit button for my other input to validate jquery can't validate the inputs, but if focus is on those inputs then jquery can validates the inputs. And sometime on click submit button inside asp:Login it also validates the inputs outside asp:Login.
How do I achieve the following 
--> When submit button inside asp:Login is clicked only inputs inside asp:Login should be checked for validation and show notification
--> When submit button outside the asp:Login is clicked inputs outside the asp:Login should be checked for validation and show notification

Answer (score 0):

Give unique id for each submit button and when the specific submit button is clicked write validation code in jquery.

```
like $(#loginsubmit).click(function)
```

Comment: Each button has unique id, but they don't work separately

Comment: If each button have unique id then you can write click event in jquery for each of those buttons based on their unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Assign different `ValidationGroup` for login control and  the controls other than  the login control.
Hence on click of the particular button, the control(s) of the respective `ValidationGroup` will be validated only.

Reference : [MSDN:Validation Group Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup(v=vs.110).aspx)